# ¿Deberíamos postular una misma pregunta en los dos idiomas?

Tags: discusión, traducciones-de-contenido

Mi pregunta es si deberiamos considerar aceptable el que yo haga una pregunta en el foro en inglés y en el foro en español.

Me gustaría saber las implicaciones que puede tener y el grado en el que lo considerariamos correcto, así como también qué medidas tomar para unificar el conocimiento (ej. ¿consideraríamos aceptable traducir respuestas de uno a otro?).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yo pienso que sí, un usuario es libre de hacerlo sin ningún problema. Eso aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar una respuesta, ya sea en el sitio en español como en el inglés. El expertiz de las personas es variados y el lenguaje inclusive influye ej ello. Además, cabe resaltar que cada comunidad reacciona diferente ante las preguntas. Un caso donde la comunidad en español apoyó a encontrar la respuesta antes que el sitio en inglés es [Cómo guardar caracteres en español e inglés en Postgres?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/13550/227) y su respectiva pregunta en el sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/q/37753158/1065197
Asimismo pueden haber preguntas donde encuentras respuesta en la comunidad en inglés antes que en las de idioma español [¿Cómo conectarme a instancia remota de WildFly utilizando JMC?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/8135/227) y la pregunta en el sitio en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/q/36750032/1065197 (este caso es el único que tengo en mente ahora, y lo pongo como válido porque nadie del sitio en español brindó una respuesta mientras que en el sitio en inglés lo hicieron, no cuento mi propia respuesta como un aporte)

Lo principal es recibir ayuda y como usuario debes buscarla en todo sitio posible. Si publicas la pregunta en un sitio externo a StackExchange como el foro msdn u otro, tampoco hay ningún problema. Lo principal creo yo es que el usuario obtenga una respuesta, y si la obtuviste de otro sitio pues convendría publicar una respuesta citando la respuesta del otro sitio.

Comment: Si, se vale preguntar en ambos sitios.  No hay problema con esto. :)

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que no hay problema en postular tu pregunta en ambos idiomas y compartir la respuesta en el sitio donde no se genero respuesta, claro con la debida traducción y haciendo la misma referencia, como método de referencia.